# Can't figure out why subnet is being updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am creating a VPC in AWS using Ansible. The following play is run

```
- name: create vpc with multi-az subnets
  ec2_vpc:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    cidr_block: "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
    resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_vpc"}'
    subnets:
      - cidr: "{{ vpc_cidr_subnet_public_0 }}"
        az: "{{ region }}{{ availability_zone_0 }}"
        resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_subnet_public_0", "Class":"web", "Partner":prefix }'
      - cidr: "{{ vpc_cidr_subnet_private_0 }}"
        az: "{{ region }}{{ availability_zone_0 }}"
        resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_subnet_private_0", "Class":"db", "Partner":prefix }'
      - cidr: "{{ vpc_cidr_subnet_private_1 }}"
        az: "{{ region }}{{ availability_zone_1 }}"
        resource_tags: '{"Name":"{{ prefix }}_subnet_private_1", "Class":"db", "Partner":prefix }'
    internet_gateway: yes
    route_tables:
      - subnets:
        - "{{ vpc_cidr_subnet_public_0 }}"
        routes:
          - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
            gw: igw
    wait: yes
  register: vpc
```

First time around this creates everything perfectly. Second time around, I expect it to not do anything as everything has been created, however, the public subnet is updated to a private one.

Why? What am I doing wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

Here are the variables:

```
---
region: eu-west-1
prefix: staging
vpc_environment: staging
vpc_cidr_block: 20.0.0.0/16
vpc_cidr_subnet_public_0: 20.0.0.0/24
vpc_cidr_subnet_private_0: 20.0.1.0/24
vpc_cidr_subnet_private_1: 20.0.2.0/24
availability_zone_0: b
availability_zone_1: c
```

Also just to clarify on what change is happening. All the resource tags of the one subnet (public) are being overwritten with the tags of another subnet (private).

Comment: After further investigation I have found that a change to the ec2_vpc.py caused this to happen. I am investigating exactly what the problem is, but it looks like it may come from this commit https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/commit/f769305bd4e96893323a965e3fa7ed68ef7dd40a

Comment: You forgot to include the most important info. What is your ansible version?

Comment: The was happening on master. I was compiling from source. To fix the issue in the interim you can point to the 2.0.0.1 stable branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in [ansible-modules-core](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core) in master - `ec2_vpc`. I have logged a [bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2930) and created a [PR](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/2931) to resolve the issue. See PR for details and the actual break. Hopefully it gets merged soon!

**[UPDATE]** Merged